# Correct usage of 74LCX245 logic level converter IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-level

I am designing a PCB where I need to convert some 5v logic signals from a Wiegand reader into 3.3v logic that a Raspberry Pi can understand.

I have been using a resistor-based voltage divider before, but that was too slow for the Wiegand data so now I am looking at using a dedicated IC for this purpose, namely the `74LCX245MTR`

Here is the schematic I have created. The `WG*-*` nets are the 5v Wiegand D0/D1 pins from 2 readers, the `H1P**` nets are pins on the Raspberry Pi header.

[image: Schematic]

The datasheet for the IC is [here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/CD00001119-250023.pdf).
Does this look correctly designed? Anything obvious missing?

Comment: Looks good to me, might want some decoupling caps on the DIR & VCC but they haven't included any in the DS schematics so it's probably fine.

Comment: I don't see why resistors would be too slow if designed correctly.

Comment: I agree with @Andy 10k series should be fast enough unless you have long coax.

Comment: 74xx245 is bidirectional, and you are using only four channels. 74xxx125 would be simpler.

Comment: Make sure that you don't accidentally exchange this particular part for a 74xxx245 from some other logic family. Some of them will not react kindly to having 5V inputs when operated from a 3.3V supply - [example](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT245.pdf), although some are fine - [example](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AHC_AHCT245.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

VCC needs bypass caps. Unused inputs should be connected to ground (or supply) voltage.

Comment: Connecting A5,6,7,8 to GND is easily done. Do you have any recommendations on a bypass cap for VCC? I haven't really messed with bypass caps before.